# what is the best solution for multi level nested view?

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/lily/9w5QU/3/

i want to show first level content, at same time, keep adding other views INSIDE first level. it will be multi level deep like that. right now the code is not nested views.

if i use CONTAINERVIEW for first level, then its content wouldn't display, if i use VIEW, then i can not add another view, or i don't know how to add it without using handle bar template.

is Ember.js good at managing multi level nested views?

Comment: It would help to know more about what you're trying to specifically accomplish

Comment: For building a single page app, need header, footer and content, but in each of them, there are other child elements. so there are multi level nested views need render and binding with the ember object. I try to find a solution, which is better for managing child views, like ContainerView, can add, delete childview. but at same time, would like to display the view itself. Since even in the footer, header level, there is certain template need render.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your example showing a multilevel nested view.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.FirstLevelView = Ember.View.create
    tagName: 'div'
    classNames: ['box']
    name: 'first level container'
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{name}} {{view secondView}}'
    secondView: Ember.View.extend
      tagName: 'div'
      classNames: ['box']
      name: 'second level container should go inside first level container'
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{name}} {{view thirdView}}'
      thirdView: Ember.View.extend
        tagName: 'div'
        classNames: ['box']
        name: 'third level view goes inside second'
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{name}}'

App.FirstLevelView.append()
```

Answer (score 0):

Still If you are not able to get the nested view in your parent view, You may do this,

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.create()
App.FirstLevelController = Ember.ObjectController.create()

App.FirstLevelView = Em.View.create
    tagName: 'div'
    classNames: ['box']
    name: 'first level container'
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile("{{name}}{{view controllers.applicationController.view.secondView}}")
    secondView: Em.View.extend
        tagName: 'div'
        classNames: ['box']
        name: 'The second level container should go inside first level container'
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile 'Hey Khajan!! {{name}}'

App.FirstLevelView.append()
```

Comment: Adding some explanation of what this is doing will make this a better answer.