# Nesting templates in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Trying to follow [this](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-router-example) example (and now have updated ember to 1.0rc2), and I want to nest templates to get started.  I have the first additional `{{outlet}}` in the `home` template, and I want it to contain two nested views (one "resume" `span9` and the other "tooltable" `span3` for you bootstrap fans).   The "resume" will again have nested template, but once I can get past this first level, I think I can the others.

According to [this SO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576853/what-is-the-best-solution-for-multi-level-nested-view), and the my edited [JS Fiddle answer](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/9w5QU/8/), I kind of see how it is done, however, the answer is in coffeescript, and the router in the example is a bit more complicated than I can quite understand (using `connectOutlets`, given some of its helper methods, which I kind of understand by themselves.

The end result should look something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/ME54A/).

But how would I get the other templates to render in the home router, as the `sections` router and the `items` router are on different paths, however, these will be a part of the index route `/`?  Do I need multiple `{{outlets}}`?, and how do I route appropriate templates to appropriate outlet placeholders?

info:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.2 
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Resume Builder</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A way to create a tailored resume from my CV" />
    <meta name="author" content="Chris Frisina" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/RB.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery.lorem.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script src="js/libs/ember1.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/libs/ember2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/RB.js"></script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="brand home" {{bindAttr class="isHome:active"}} {{action "doHome"}}>Chris Frisina</div>
            <div class="nav-collapse pull-right">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="sections"><a>1</a></li>
                <li class="sections"><a>2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <h3 class="demo-panel-title">This is the index template</h3>
      {{home}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- This is where I resume template should be placed -->
        {{resume}}
        <!-- This is where I tooltable template should be placed -->
        {{tooltable}}
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="resume">
      <div class="span9">
        <h1>Viewer</h1>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tooltable">
      <div class="span3">
        <div id="tooltable" class="tooltable hero-unit affix">
          <h1>Tooltable</h1>
          <p>Selector 1</p>
          <p>Selector 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js :

```
// Attach the application to window
window.RB = Ember.Application.create({});

// Define the main application controller. This is automatically picked up by
// the application and initialized.
RB.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

});
RB.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});

// Router
RB.Router = Ember.Router.extend({

});
RB.Router.map(function(){

});

// Home
RB.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
});
RB.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'home',
});
// Resume
RB.ResumeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});
RB.ResumeView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'resume'
});

// Tooltable
RB.TooltableController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});
RB.TooltableView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'tooltable'
});

//Defer the start until advanceReadiness() is complete
// cant init RB manually, must use advanceReadiness(), which needs defer...
RB.deferReadiness();
// var test = function() {
  RB.advanceReadiness();
// });
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer the entire question but I can start out by giving an example of how you would nest your templates and write a route to work with them

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
    this.resource("days", { path: "/days" }, function() {
        this.resource("day", { path: "/:day_id" }, function() {
            this.resource("appointments", { path: "/appointments" }, function() {
                this.resource("appointment", { path: "/:appointment_id" }, function() {
                    this.route("edit", { path: "/edit" });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

For the example route above I plan to have the user click from /days to a specific day /days/1

then inside that day I want them to have the ability to show all the appointments

then inside the appointments I want to give them the ability to "click" on a specific apt and show it or edit it

Because my app starts with the days route, in my app index I want to jump to days right away when the app launches (so instead of starting at / my app starts at /days for example)

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('days');
    }
});
```

The templates look like this

application.handlebars (or if you inline it)

```
{{outlet}}
```

days.handlebars

```
{{#each day in controller}}
  {{#linkTo 'day' day}}view details about the day{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

day.handlebars

```
{{#linkTo "appointments" target="controller"}}show all the apts{{/linkTo}}
```

appointments.handlebars

```
{{#each appointment in controller}}
<a href="#" {{action 'addAppointment' appointment target="view"}}>{{appointment.start}} - {{appointment.end}}</a><br />
{{/each}}
```

My appointments route looks like this (to provide the appointments in the above template)

```
App.AppointmentsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var day = this.modelFor("day");
        return day.get('appointments');
    }
});
```